# Spring ResponseEntityExceptionHandler does not resolve override messages

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am overriding the BindException by extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

I supplied my custom messages in property bundle . However, its not getting recognized by ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

It does resolve for TypeMistMatch on controller request parameters.
But it does not inside ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

Am I missing something?

```
@Component
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleBindException(final org.springframework.validation.BindException ex,
            final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
        //
        final List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        for (final ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getGlobalErrors()) {
            errors.add(error.getObjectName() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        final ErrorMessage apiError = new ErrorMessage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), errors.toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Msg.properties

```
typeMismatch.demoPojo.instant= Supposed to be a date
typeMismatch.instant=Instant field
typeMismatch.java.time.Instant=Instant type
```

Comment: Should not your `@Override` annotated method `handleBindException` should also be annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Included anotation "@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)" in my @ControlerAdvice solved my problema that it's same with yours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define getters in ErrorMessage class.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed that tutorial as well and the error isn't in this class. It's in the class apiError. You should generate getters and setters, something that wasn't shown on the tutorial.

Tutorial link: http://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Comment: Please share the main points of that answer here instead of only linking to an external resource